# Qual a função sintática de "pelo organismo" na frase "Isso dependia das substâncias segregadas pelo organismo"?

Tags: análise-morfossintática

**"Isso dependia das substâncias segregadas pelo organismo"**.

Estou na dúvida se **"pelo organismo"** seria **adjunto adnominal (AA)** ou **complemento nominal (CN)**.

De acordo com meu estudo, poderia ser adjunto adnominal por ser um termo agente e ter função adjetiva. Contudo, também li que o AA subordina-se a substantivo concreto ou abstrato, mas acho que não é o caso.

Por outro lado, poderia ser CN porque é subordinado a um adjetivo. Um CN está sempre ligado a um processo de regência nominal. Seria esse o caso? ("segregada por")

Answer (score 3):

Adjunto adnominal não pode ser, pois o adjunto adnominal subordina-se, como dizes, a um substantivo, coisa que *segregadas* não é. Complementos nominais subordinam-se a adjetivos (como em *sou responsável pelo erro*), substantivos e advérbios, logo se considerássemos *segregadas* como adjetivo,  *pelo organismo* seria o seu complemento nominal. No entanto, segundo a análise [deste artigo no Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/complemento-do-adjetivo-vs-agente-da-passiva/35100) e [este outro](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/adjectivo-ou-participio/4272) a frases do mesmo tipo (como *segundo a cronologia feita por Pessoa […]*), o *segregadas* é verbo e não adjetivo.

Então, ***pelo organismo*** é **agente da passiva**, e ***segregadas pelo organismo*** é uma **oração subordinada reduzida de particípio**. Esta é também a análise na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra  (Lisboa, 2014, doravante C&C, p. 756-7), que passo a citar:

> […] as orações subordinadas substantivas, adjetivas e adverbiais podem estar:
>
> 1.º) Desenvolvidas […]
>
> 2.º) Reduzidas, quando não apresentam nexo subordinativo e têm o verbo no infinitivo, no gerúndio ou no particípio:
> […]
>
> > Que seria do Futuro se trocássemos esses hábitos / **consagrados pela experiência** / e nos deixássemos arrastar pelos falsos profetas?

Especificamente sobre o agente da passiva, diz o  [Clube do Português](https://clubedoportugues.com.br/agente-da-passiva/):

> Às vezes, o agente da passiva vem ligado a apenas um verbo no particípio em vez de locução verbal. Isso acontece quando a oração é reduzida de particípio.
> […]
> *A pressão **feita pela professora** surtiu efeito*.

Portanto a tua frase e a seguinte são equivalentes:

> Isso dependia das substâncias **segregadas pelo organismo**
>
> Isso dependia das substâncias **que foram segregadas pelo organismo**

Em ambas, o parte a negrito é uma oração subordinada adjetiva que modifica o nome *substâncias*. No teu exemplo a oração é reduzida de particípio; *pelo organismo* é o agente da passiva em ambas.

### Complementos, adjuntos e sintagmas preposicionais

*Pelo organismo* é um sintagma preposicional, porque é encabeçado por uma preposição: *por* (na forma contraída *pelo*). **Sintagmas preposicionais podem exercer várias funções sintáticas**, por exemplo (exemplos tirados de C&C, p. 174 – 200):

- **Ajunto**, adnominal (“homem *de consciência*”) ou adverbial (“dançar *no meio da sala*”);
- **complemento nominal** (“nojo *de si mesma*”);
- **Complemento verbal**: complemento indireto (“quem daria dinheiro *aos pobres*”), complemento oblíquo (“duvidava *da riqueza da terra*”), predicativo do sujeito (“esta linha é *de morte*”), predicativo do complemento direto (“deixou o avozinho *de rastos*”), ou agente da passiva (“um jornal é lido *por muita gente*”).

Ora, o agente da passiva é um complemento verbal (C&C, p. 194); não é um adjunto. C&C (p. 200)  apresenta um teste para distinguir entre os dois. Num par *o que aconteceu ao [sujeito]? – resposta*, um adjunto adverbial tanto pode aparecer na pergunta como na resposta; complementos só podem aparecer na resposta. Por exemplo, em *substâncias segregadas após o estímulo pelo organismo*, o constituinte *após os estímulo* gera frases gramaticais tanto na pergunta como na resposta, mostrando assim que é um adjunto:

> Que aconteceu às substâncias? — Foram segregadas **após os estímulo** pelo organismo.
>
> Que aconteceu às substâncias **após o estímulo**? — Foram segregadas pelo organismo.

Mas *pelo organismo* só pode aparecer na resposta (como nas frases acima); na pergunta gera uma frase agramatical (indicado por *), mostrando assim que é um complemento:

> *Que aconteceu às substâncias **pelo organismo**? — Foram segregadas (após o estímulo).
>
> *Que aconteceu às substâncias após o estímulo **pelo organismo**? — Foram segregadas.

A lógica deste tipo de teste vem explicada na *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa, 2013, vol. II, p. 1163-4): o verbo mantém com os seus complementos uma relação muito mais estreita do que com os adjuntos adverbiais; C&C dizem que os complementos são “termos integrantes” da oração (C&C, p. 180-1), enquanto os adjuntos são “temos acessórios” (C&C, p. 197); por isso o complemento tem de ficar junto do seu verbo (na mesma oração; não necessariamente adjacente); o adjunto pode ficar separado. O teste da *Gramática do Português* é diferente, para frases ativas. Aplicado diretamente a frases passivas ficaria estranho (?*O que as substâncias fizeram foi serem segregadas* ??). Mas adaptando com *acontecer*, dá igualmente frases agramaticais quando se separa o complemento do verbo:

> *O que aconteceu às substâncias **pelo organismo** foi serem segregadas (após o estímulo).
>
> *O que aconteceu às substâncias após o estímulo **pelo organismo** foi serem segregadas.

Com o adjunto não há problema:

> O que aconteceu às substâncias **após o estímulo** foi serem segregadas **pelo organismo**.

Comment: Sim, tambem é isso.

Answer (score 1):

> "Sintagma Preposicional (SP) É a unidade que se liga a outra por meio
> de uma preposição, sendo esse o seu núcleo:
>
> Foram para o parque **em fila".**

**pelo organismo: sintagma preposicional**

[Sintagmas em português](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/819105/mod_folder/content/0/_Textos%20da%20Bibliografia%20Complementar/Teoria%20Gramatical%20e%20Sintaxe%20do%20portugu%C3%AAs/OTHERO_GramaticaDaFraseEmPortugues.pdf)

PRIBERAM

"pe·lo |pêlu| ou |plu|
(per + lo)
contracção
Aglutinação da preposição antiga per e do artigo ou pronome lo.

Feminino: pela."

Pelo é uma preposiçao

**Com **função sintáctica** de adjunto adverbial. Veja o link acima.**

> "Rotulamos todos esses sintagmas como sintagmas preposicionais
> independentemente da função sintática que o agrupamento exerce na
> frase. Perini (1989, 2000, 2006), por outro lado, classifica alguns de
> nossos PPs como sendo sintagmas adverbiais, por eles ocuparem uma
> função sintática típica de adjuntos adverbiais".

Comment: Portanto o teu argumento é: *pelo organismo* é um sintagma preposicional (é), portanto "tem função sintática de adjunto adverbial" porque **alguns** sintagmas preposicionais têm função sintática de adjunto adverbial! Isto não tem lógica. É como dizer que o João é homem, portanto é advogado, porque alguns homens são advogados.

Comment: Não sou eu que digo isso. É o autor do artigo.

Comment: Leste mal. O autor diz: "classifica **alguns de nossos PPs** [...] por eles ocuparem [...]"; não diz que classifica todos os PPs.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu não disse todos os PPs. E para mim, a pergunta é um deles. Não vejo o problema. https://www.jussiup.com.br/2018/05/sintagmas.html

Comment: Então o teu argumento é: o exemplo da pergunta é adjunto adverbial porque para mim é! E nem sequer explicas por que é que para ti é. Não há nada no excerto que citaste (nem no resto da secção sobre sintagmas preposicionais) que justifique a tua posição.